# MVVM Modal Dialog using Service Locator

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I am developing a WPF application that follows MVVM pattern. To display modal dialogs, I am trying to follow the way the following articles suggests.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern?fid=1541292&fr=26#xx0xx

But in these kind of articles, What I have observed, that ShowDialog method of DialogService interface is called from MainWindowViewModel.

Situation in my application is slightly different.
MainWindow.xaml contains a user control say ChildView that contains a button Add.
MainWindowViewModel contains another ViewModel say ChildVM that is bind with ChildView.
ChildVM contains AddCommand, and I need to display Modal Dialog when AddExecute method
corresponding to AddCommand is called.
How can I accomplish that?

Edited Code

```
     private Window FindOwnerWindow(object viewModel)
            {
                    FrameworkElement view = null;

        // Windows and UserControls are registered as view.
        // So all the active windows and userControls are contained in views
        foreach (FrameworkElement viewIterator in views)
        {
            // Check whether the view is an Window
            // If the view is an window and dataContext of the window, matches
            // with the viewModel, then set view = viewIterator
            Window viewWindow = viewIterator as Window;
            if (null != viewWindow)
            {
                if (true == ReferenceEquals(viewWindow.DataContext, viewModel))
                {
                    view = viewWindow;
                    break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // Check whether the view is an UserControl
                // If the view is an UserControl and Content of the userControl, matches
                // with the viewModel, then set view = userControl
                // In case the view is an user control, then find the Window that contains the
                // user control and set it as owner
                System.Windows.Controls.UserControl userControl = viewIterator as System.Windows.Controls.UserControl;
                if (null != userControl)
                {
                    if (true == ReferenceEquals(userControl.Content, viewModel))
                    {
                        view = userControl;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if (view == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Viewmodel is not referenced by any registered View.");
        }

        // Get owner window
        Window owner = view as Window;
        if (owner == null)
        {
            owner = Window.GetWindow(view);
        }

        // Make sure owner window was found
        if (owner == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("View is not contained within a Window.");
        }

        return owner;
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Anirban, follow this article from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application and look how the modal dialog works. I have used this article to help me create my apps. Hope this helps!

Comment: The approach is same as the link I provided.

Comment: This looks fine, though in my opinion it's kind of a misconception to put the ViewModel inside the content of your UserControl. That's not really the point of UserControls. Why don't you use a ContentControl then? But I don't really have an insight. I would consider setting the DataContext, rather than the content, if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, if I get you right, you want to open the modal dialog not from the MainWindowViewModel, but from a different ChildViewModel?

Have a look at the constructors of the MainWindowViewModel of the CodeProject article that you have linked:

The ViewModel has a constructor with the following signature:

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel(
            IDialogService dialogService,
            IPersonService personService,
            Func<IOpenFileDialog> openFileDialogFactory)
```

This means that for construction you need the service which shows the modal dialogs, another service (personService), which doesn't matter here and a factory for the specific dialog to open files, openFileDialogFactory.

In order to use the service, which is the core part of the article, a simple ServiceLocator is implemented and a default constructor is defined, which uses the ServiceLocator to get instances of the services that the ViewModel needs:

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel()
            : this(
            ServiceLocator.Resolve<IDialogService>(),
            ServiceLocator.Resolve<IPersonService>(),
            () => ServiceLocator.Resolve<IOpenFileDialog>())
        {}
```

This is possible, because ServiceLocator is static. Alternatively, you could set the local field for the services in the constructor, using the ServiceLocator. The above approach is better, because it allows you to set the services yourself, if you don't want to use the ServiceLocator.

You can do exactly the same in your own ChildViewModel.

```cs
public ChildViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
}
```

Create an default constructor, which calls the above constructor with the service instance resolved from the ServiceLocator:

```cs
public ChildViewModel() : this(ServiceLocator.Resolve<IDialogService>()) {}
```

And now you can use the service from anywhere in your ChildViewModel like this:

```cs
_dialogService.ShowDialog<WhateverDialog>(this, vmForDialog);
```

In order to find the owner window of your view, which is not a view itself, you need to modify the `FindOwnerWindow` method of the DialogService to find the parent window of the view, rather than expecting a Window as the view itself. You can use the VisualTreeHelper to do so:

```cs
private Window FindOwnerWindow(object viewModel)
    {
        var view = views.SingleOrDefault(v => ReferenceEquals(v.DataContext, viewModel));

        if (view == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Viewmodel is not referenced by any registered View.");
        }

        DependencyObject owner = view;

        // Iterate through parents until a window is found, 
        // if the view is not a window itself
        while (!(owner is Window))
        {
            owner = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(owner);
            if (owner == null) 
                throw new Exception("No window found owning the view.");
        }

        // Make sure owner window was found
        if (owner == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("View is not contained within a Window.");
        }

        return (Window) owner;
    }
```

You still need to register the UserControl though, setting the attached property on the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChildView"
             ...
             Service:DialogService.IsRegisteredView="True">
   ...
 </UserControl>
```

As far as I can tell, this works.

**Additional information:**

To accomplish the same thing, I use the PRISM framework, which comes with a lot of functionality for exactly this kind of decoupling, Inversion of Control (IoC) and dependency injection (DI). Maybe it is worth it to have a look at it for you, too.

Hope this helps!

**Edited to consider the comment.**

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that the child viewModel corresponds to an user control instead of an window like the MainWindoViewModel. _dialogService.ShowDialog<WhateverDialog>(this, vmForDialog) .. When the dialogService tries to find out the Window that have the dataContext as "this", it fails. Please have a look at the FindOwnerWindow method of DialogService implementation.

Comment: I hope I have solved the problem. In my application, corresponding viewmodel of any user control is associated with the user control as Content of the user control, not as the DataContext. So I needed to modify the the FindOwnerWindow method. Please have a look at my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

See if you like this idea... I'm using Castle Windsor and Prism, so your mileage may vary, but the concepts should be the same with another MVVM and IoC.

You start with your MainViewModel.cs that wants to open a modal dialog

```
var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SomeDialogView>();
view.ShowDialog();
```

but of course it's not honoring what you set in MainView.xaml

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
```

Drat!

But wait, couldn't ServiceLocator just give me the MainView?

```
var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SomeDialogView>();
view.Owner = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainView>();  // sure, why not?
view.ShowDialog();
```

This line throws an exception with my IoC configuration, since my IoC registers views to have a "transient lifetime". In Castle Windsor, this means each request is provided a brand new instance, and I need *the* MainView instance itself, not a new one that hasn't been shown.

But by simply changing the registration from every view being "transient"

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("WhateverAssemblyTheyreIn")
  .InNamespace("WhateverNamespaceTheyreIn")
  .LifestyleTransient());
```

to be slightly more discriminating by using the fluent Unless() and If()

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("WhateverAssemblyTheyreIn")
  .InNamespace("WhateverNamespaceTheyreIn")
  .Unless(type => type == typeof(MainView))
  .LifestyleTransient());  // all as before but MainView.

container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("WhateverAssemblyTheyreIn")
  .InNamespace("WhateverNamespaceTheyreIn")
  .If(type => type == typeof(MainView))
  .LifestyleSingleton());  // set MainView to singleton!
```

the MainView provided *is* the one we wanted!

HTH